# How do I build a customizable dashboard solution on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dashboard

Our product requires support for a high level dashboard highlighting metrics pertaining to the business modeled by the product. Its a B2B product with a web application as a front-end.

We use Amazon RDS to store business data.  What is the best approach to build a customizable dashboard in AWS?

The traditional approach would be to create metrics, process business data (analysis) and store the metrics/results in output tables. And then use a fancy charts library in the web application to build a support a panel/chart/graphic view per such metric. Support drill downs etc.

However, I believe this approach is outdated and too much work. Are there any readmade solutions available? Ideally, I should just be able to push results data to a third party solution, and the third party solution should allow for creation of custom dashboards (custom implies that the user can choose to select particular metrics/panels he would like to see in the dashboard, and their relative order& position in the dashboard) and embedding them in the products web application, to enable to end user to view as well as customize dashboards.

I'm aware of AWS quicksight, but it does not support embedding output views/dashboards into a web application. 
I like Azure Power BI; At least you get to embed the dashboard in the web application, but I do not believe the end user  can customize the embedded view. And ofcourse, Azure PowerBI is not on AWS ;).

Is there a mature 3rd party solution that we can evaluate? The scale of the data is very very small. So we are not looking for a high performance enterprise solution (might be too expensive anyway!). However, the need for customizability of dashboards view is high.

Answer (score 2):

Embedded dashboards were added to QuickSight in November 2018, so you can now use that tool if you'd prefer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/embedded-dashboards-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Tableau is the first possibility, but it is expensive.

Infogram may also be an option: https://infogram.com/examples/dashboards

If you have small data volumes and you want cusomisation you may unfortunately have to look into writing or at least customising an existing solution.